# How to save void* returned from jni in java for later use

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm writing a Java wrapper for a JNI C function that returns a "handle" - a void* - and I need to save the value accurately to be able to pass it back to another JNI function later.  In the C code, I could cast the void* to an unsigned long, but Java doesn't have either unsigned or long values.

Specifically, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
// in C
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_hooks_ll_Dlopen(JNIEnv* env,jstring j_filename,jint flag)
{
    const char* filename = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,j_filename,0);
    return (int) dlopen(filename,flag);
}
JNIEXPORT jvoid JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_hooks_ll_Dlclose(JNIEnv* env,jint handle)
{
    dlclose(handle);
}

// in Java
public static native int ll_Dlopen(String filename,int flag);
public static native void ll_Dlclose(int handle);

int handle=ll_Dlopen("filename.so",0);
    .
    .
    .
ll_Dlclose(handle);
```

The Java code isn't going to do anything with the handle other than pass it back to the JNI code.  My question is whether it's safe to use a Java int for this?  If not, what data type *should* I be using?

N.B. - The code above is an overly simplified illustration of the problem, not an accurate representation of the code I'm working with.

Comment: Regarding "java doesn't have `long` values": the list of [java primitive-types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) explicitly lists long as a "64-bit 2's-complement integer".

Comment: @Paul - Thanks.  I missed that.  I believe that would make long the correct data type to use.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in @Paul's comment, Java's long type is a 64-bit integer.  Since the pointer value is only treated as an opaque value while in Java, the code in my question is correct when the Java int value is replaced by Java long:

```
// in C
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_hooks_ll_Dlopen(JNIEnv* env,jstring j_filename,jint flag)
{
    const char* filename = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,j_filename,0);
    return (unsigned long) dlopen(filename,flag);
}
JNIEXPORT jvoid JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_hooks_ll_Dlclose(JNIEnv* env,jlong handle)
{
    dlclose((void*)(unsigned long)handle);
}

// in Java
public static native long ll_Dlopen(String filename,int flag);
public static native void ll_Dlclose(long handle);

long handle=ll_Dlopen("filename.so",0);
    .
    .
    .
ll_Dlclose(handle);
```

Comment: isn't unsigned long still only 32-bit in C, shouldn't it be (unsigned long long) ?